# adicionar driver sql server en jaspersoft

Tags: java, jasper-reports, jasper

Estoy intentando crear un Data Adapters que se conecte a sql server 2008. Cuando creo el Data Adapters selecciono el driver que me da a seleccionar para sql server pongo:

bd: `RecursosHum`

usuario: `sa`

password: `sa`

pero cuando le doy a test me da error:

```
Reason:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

Pienso que el problema es que el jaspersoft no tiene instalado el driver de sql server e buscado como agregar driver al jasper pero no  he encontrado nada que me sea de utilidad.

Probé con poner el driver que descargué en la carpeta plugins del jaspersoft pero nada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es necesario incluir el archivo MS SQL Server JDBC JAR en Jaspersoft Studio.Lo puedes descargar del sitio web de Microsoft. Luego, para utilizarlos en Jaspersoft Studio hacer esto:

1. Haga clic en su proyecto en el Explorador de proyectos y seleccione Construir Path->Configure Build Path.
2. En la pestaña Libraries Clic en Add External JARs...
3. Encontrar el archivo JDBC JAR.